# Can a data that show file path downloadable using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to make a page where the page can display a list of data and users can download the data. First, the data is a file name and the file name is like a filepath. For example C/user/file.pdf. Below is my coding:

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    //byte[] bytes;
    string fileName;
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Ulysses"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME FROM OLE_LINK";
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                fileName = sdr["OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    //Response.ContentType = contentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    //Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Below is my HTML coding:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME" HeaderText="File Name"/>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Is it possible to download a data like that or not. If can, the page can display the data but I cannot download the file when I click the download link. Is there anything wrong with my coding? Here is the link of tutorial that I use as a guide: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-files-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: What error are you getting? Also why `TOP 10` in query. You are downloading a single file using id arg from clicked button.

Comment: The file has more than that and for starters, I want to show a list of 10 data in the table. The page can give user the freedom to choose whichever filethey want. I dont have any error but when I click at the download link, it does not download the file that I choose.